# Update message list when receiving a notification

Tags: android

I can't go much into detail, so this is going to be brief. I have a class which let's me receive notifications. I also have a class which holds a function that lets me update my message list. I am using firebase messaging. In the part about creating a notification, I try to add a call to the function that refreshes my message list, but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: yes, show your code..

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code, my suggestion would be to do a broadcast when you receive a notification and then your desired activity will register for broadcast and if the activity is on screen it will receive broadcast and do the appropriate operation.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it. I am a beginner at android studio.